# Extent of Gebroks

Tags: minhag, passover, gebrochts

For those who have the minhag not to eat Gebroks on Pesach, how about dipping into undiluted fruit juices, which do not cause leavening? And what about dipping in water and eating it right away, before the 18 minutes that would be necessary for *chimutz* to occur?

Comment: I know people have varying degrees of _chumra_, so each of your questions might have more than one answer.

Comment: ... how about buying matza that's reputably supervised, such that matza with unbaked flour in it doesn't leave the production line?

Comment: @Issac Moses Don't think it's practical. How do you check for flour?

Comment: @yydl How do you eat matza to begin with?

Comment: @Isaac - those who are stringent about gebroks do not differentiate between bakeries or supervisions. And as yydl said, how can you possibly check for unbaked flour in a matzah?

Comment: VEry simple. Bake Rekikin (cracker matzoh) instead of Lehem. Oh wait! We already do that so Gebrochts is not really a real concern nowadays except as keeping  a minhag that started as a hanhagah tovah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Halachically Speaking just did an entire issue on this topic. Seems there are various minhagim.

http://www.thehalacha.com/attach/Volume7/Issue4.pdf